# how to pull all VMs and its associated storage using govc

Tags: vmware-vcenter, parsing

I'm able to connect to Vcenter using govc, however I would like get a list of all VMs within a specific folder with it storage(Related Objects) or datastore cluster in a comma separated format.

Can someone help me with the govc command to get the desired output as below:

vm1, storagecluster1
vm2, storagecluster4
vm3, storagecluster1
vm4, storagecluster2

```bash
# Connect to vCenter using govc
govc about || { echo "Failed to connect to vCenter."; exit 1; }

Name:         VMware vCenter Server
Vendor:       VMware, Inc.
Version:      7.0.3
Build:        22357613
OS type:      linux-x64
API type:     VirtualCenter
API version:  7.0.3.0
```

Comment: "Can someone help me with the govc command" - have you tried the govc github support page?

Comment: yes I did, I didn't get a direct switch where I can pull that information what I'm looking for.